# Swift UIWebView detect scroll

Tags: swift, scroll, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` where I'm rendering a PDF.
I need a method that hide the GUI if the pdf is not at the beginning of the page and show it again if the `WebView` hit the top. How can I check this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `scrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidScroll` for that like this way.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0) {
        //Do what you want.
    }
}
```

**Note:** Don't forgot to set `scrollView` delegate of `webView` like this `self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self`

Comment: with this the "print" is never call : func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    print("test");
}   i have delegate the UIWebView to self but notthing

Comment: "Cannot assign value of type myViewController to type 'UiScrollViewDelegate?'"